# Azure bot deployment

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-bot-service

I am trying to deploy an Azure bot. When I try to run:

```
az deployment sub create --template-file "deploymentTemplates/template-with-new-rg.json" --location francecentral --parameters appType="MultiTenant" appId="aa14566a-c201-4488-8e7c-be837b921c50" appSecret="guyguyg" botId="bottest" botSku=F0 bottestservice
```

I get:

> unrecognized template parameter 'appType'. Allowed parameters: appId,
> appSecret, botId, botSku, groupLocation, groupName,
> newAppServicePlanLocation, newAppServicePlanName,
> newAppServicePlanSku, newWebAppName

I have Azure Cli 2.30.0 (installed via Brew in MacOS)

Comment: Can you share what exactly you’re confused about or stuck on? It’s pretty clear to me that the template in question doesn’t take a parameter called `appType`. Can you share why you believe the case to be otherwise?

Comment: My command line is based on what is written on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cmultitenant

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `appType` may not be the problem itself. The commands appear to have changed recently, and that's a new one. However, your command has several other issues, and thus it's likely that the service is simply throwing an error where it first encounters a problem. Firstly, `bottestservice` is entered without a parameter declaration. The service has no idea what that means.

Futhermore, the command to create a bot with a new Resource Group (I assumed you want to do this because you entered the command that has `--template-file "deploymentTemplates/template-with-new-rg.json`) requires several more parameters such as `newAppServicePlanName`, `newWebAppName`, `groupName`, `groupLocation`, `newAppServicePlanLocation`, and `name`. The last valid parameter you supplied was `botSku`. With several important parameters missing, it's possible that this is the source of your issue.

Please review the documentation you posted again and ensure you are entering the commands exactly and supplying all the required parameters. I got all of this from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today, and the fix was simple: I had accidentally CD'd into an older project folder instead of the current project folder, and that older project had been using the older version of the deploy templates.

Check that your deployment template file is using the current schema, which appears to be 2019-04-01 and not an older schema such as 2015-01-01, as those older versions don't contain the 'appType' parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).